# How do I start the wpa_cli on android device?

Tags: android, adb

I've rooted my android device because I'm trying to make it detect ad-hoc wifi.

I installed BusyBox pro and then I typed in the adb shell:

```
su -c "/system/bin/wpa_cli -p /data/misc/wifi/"
```

in order to start the wpa_cli shell it returned

```
/system/bin/sh: wpa_cli: not found
```

and I'm really confused. I wonder on what I missed. Can anybody help?

Answer (score 2):

The wpa_cli shell is only needed to operate and monitor wpa_supplicant. If the WPA system is already configured, wpa_cli is not needed at runtime. Many manufacturers remove the wpa_cli executable from their systems to prevent users from changing how wifi is working. The Google Nexus devices include wpa_cli in their eng and userdebug builds, and may even include it in the user builds.

I would find the exact OS version on your device, check out an AOSP sandbox branched to that same version, and then build wpa_cli. This can be done by using lunch to select your device, and then do an "mma" in external/wpa_supplicant_8. You can then push wpa_cli from $OUT/system/bin onto your device at /system/bin, and it should run.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `wpa_supplicant` instead of `wpa_cli`.

Make sure you have `wpa_supplicant` first by `ls /system/bin | grep wpa`

Comment: I tried to run `su -c "/system/bin/wpa_cli -p /data/misc/wifi/" ` but it seems like that's not the correct usage. I then tried  `wpa_supplicant -Dwext -iwlan0 -c/etc/wpa_supplicant.conf` it returns nothing, no info, no news, no  interactive shell.

Comment: @Leyonce Are you using root user?

Comment: made a typo error in the first comment, i typed:      `   `/system/bin/wpa_supplicant -c/data/misc/wifi`   in the adb shell

Comment: I want to remove wifi network from device. This can be achieve using **adb shell wap_cli remove_network {networkId}**. How can i achieve this using **wpa_supplicant**?? After the update of my os, i ma not able to use wpa_cli command @StephenLin